# How to keep my aside from being pushed below my form?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have the following code. When I shrink the screen and the width of the screen is less then 800px, the aside will be pushed down, below the form. I want the aside to stay on the right of form, and a horizontal appears when the screen is less than what the div needs.

Am I missing something? Hope I don't have to change the style of div and article.

```
<article style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden">
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 20%; min-width: 800px">
    <form style="width: 500px; float: left;">
    </form>
    <aside style="width: 260px; float: left; margin-left:40px>
    </aside>
</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a small syntax error on the aside style attribute (you're missing the closing ") but it seems to work when I test it. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I am using chrome. And I also tested it on Safari and Firefox